# Azure Webapp HttpListener

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service, httplistener

I created a simple C# console application (net7.0) as a server for my multiplayer card game.
It uses *HttpListener* to receive connection requests, then upgrades to a websocket connection.

```cs
// Start listening for websocket requests
public async void Start()
{
    HttpListener listener = new();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/cardgame/");
    listener.Start();

    #if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    #endif

    while (true)
    {
        HttpListenerContext listenerContext = await listener.GetContextAsync();
        if (listenerContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            ProcessRequest(listenerContext);
        }
        else
        {
            listenerContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            listenerContext.Response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This works on my windows laptop, when running the app as admin or using the `netsh add urlacl url=http://+:80/cardgame user=DOMAIN\user` in CMD beforehand.

I want to host this in **Azure Cloud as a Webapp** using the 'Free' settings. Deployment was successful, but when starting the webapp it throws an **access denied exception because of the HttpListener**. The exact scenario: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9haN.png)

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
```

I also tried it with `listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/");` and with the public IP of the webapp at the place of the '+' sign, but to no avail.

Azure Kudu environment doesn't run the app in admin mode, but it also doesn't allow the `netsh` command to be configured, so I'm stating to feel like this is not possible to do... But then what is this webapp environment good for if you can't even listen to a port? (for ASP.NET I suppose...)

**I would really appreciate if anybody could help me out with this:**

- Is there a way to configure a websocket connection on Azure Webapp environment using a C# console application?
- What other solution would allow me to host my server in cloud this way (preferably free)?

Comment: You can do it on the [Cloud Services - Extended Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/overview) runtime. I'm not sure if there is a free tier for this, but you can run it pretty low cost on minimal resources.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into that.

Comment: @Bence Fabo  Have you   tried with `Azure signal` and `Azure Web PubSub Service`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to configure a WebSocket connection on Azure Web App environment using a C# console application.

> We can deploy an  [ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net70&pivots=development-environment-vs),  [ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0),  [ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0#azure-app-service), and  [ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1044950/How-to-Publish-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-Application-to-Azur)  web app to Azure App Service.

- Use Azure Web PubSub Service and Azure SignalR as WebSockets in Azure.
- The following code creates a WebSocket connection and allows the user to send and receive messages.

**Using Azure Web PubSub Service in Blazor:**

```
@page "/websocket"

<h1>Echo test</h1>
<h3>State: @webSocket.State</h3>

@if(webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open) {
    <form @onsubmit="SendMessageAsync">
        Message: <input @bind="@message" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
    <pre>@log</pre>
}

@code {

    
    private CancellationTokenSource disposalTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private ClientWebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
    private string message = "Hello, websocket!";
    private string log = "";


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        await ConnectWebSocketAsync();
        _ = ReceiveLoop();
    }

    private async Task ConnectWebSocketAsync() {
        // Update the URI with your actual WebSocket endpoint and access token
        var uri = new Uri("wss://your-websocket-endpoint?access_token=your-access-token");
        await webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri, disposalTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private async Task SendMessageAsync() {
        log += $"Sending: {message}\n";
        var dataToSend = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        await webSocket.SendAsync(dataToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, disposalTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private async Task ReceiveLoop() {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        while(!disposalTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            var received = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, disposalTokenSource.Token);
            if (received.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text) {
                var receivedAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, received.Count);
                log += $"Received: {receivedAsText}\n";
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        disposalTokenSource.Cancel();
        _ = webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Bye", CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

**Local:**

[image]

[image]

- I followed the reference [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for Publishing an ASP .NET Core app to Azure with Visual Studio .

**Azure:**
[image]

**For Azure SignalR  with  Blazor :**

> I followed the reference for the [configuration](https://www.blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/32)  of Azure  SignalR in [Blazor](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/ServerSideBlazor)

- Install  package
  `dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.SignalR`
- The below code is for the [configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/ChatRoomLocal) of Azure  SignalR with  Blazor

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();
    ...
}
```

**appsetting.json:**

```js
  "Azure": {
    "SignalR": {
      "Enabled": true,
      "ConnectionString": <your-connection-string>
    }
  }
```

**Local:**
[image]

[image]

[image]
**Azure:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Azure PubSub would do the job perfectly.