# azure Web PubSub Service. event handler for incoming client messages

Tags: c#, websocket, azure-web-pubsub

Using Azure web pubsub service.
We use .net framework 4.8 (not .net CORE).
Trying to subscribe to incoming messages from clients.

Following is our service code (simplified):

```
using Azure.Messaging.WebPubSub;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pubsubservice
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string cs = "Endpoint=https://mypubsub.webpubsub.azure.com;AccessKey=MyKey;Version=1.0;";
        private const string hub = "Hub";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceClient = new
            WebPubSubServiceClient(cs, hub);

            Console.WriteLine("Server is running...");

            serviceClient.SendToAll("Hello");

            Console.WriteLine("\n Server - Type 'exit' to exit.\n");
            var msg = Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

The service works as expected.

This is my pubsub client tester :

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PubsubClient
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static string url = "wss://mypubsub.webpubsub.azure.com/client/hubs/Hub?access_token=MyToken";

        private static object consoleLock = new object();
        private const int sendChunkSize = 256;
        private const int receiveChunkSize = 64;
        private const bool verbose = true;
        private static readonly TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Connect(url).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task Connect(string uri)
        {
            ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;

            try
            {
                webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
                await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.WhenAll(Receive(webSocket), Send(webSocket));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (webSocket != null)
                    webSocket.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine();

                lock (consoleLock)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task Send(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sendChunkSize];

            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                random.NextBytes(buffer);

                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, CancellationToken.None);
                LogStatus(false, buffer, buffer.Length);

                await Task.Delay(delay);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[receiveChunkSize];
            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    LogStatus(true, buffer, result.Count);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void LogStatus(bool receiving, byte[] buffer, int length)
        {
            lock (consoleLock)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = receiving ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} bytes... ", receiving ? "Received" : "Sent", length);

                if (verbose)
                    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, length));

                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The websocket is established successfully , the client sends and receive data.

My question is how do I handle the sent data in the server?
Is there an event (e.g. OnMessage, OnMessageReceived)?
The client seems to send the message but I cannot figure how to handle it in the server.

Thanks

Comment: Using Azure web pub sub there is no  event (e.g. OnMessage, OnMessageReceived)?  but with `WebSocketSharp`  we have OnMessage [reference](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the code that creates a WebSocket connection and allows the user to send and receive [messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77494083/azure-webapp-httplistener/77536987#77536987).

I followed the process of setting up WebSockets with .NET in an App Service, both for Windows and Linux plans, using [onmessage](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/HowTo/WebSockets/use_websockets_with_dotnet.md).

**index.html**

```js
  sendButton.onclick = function () {
            if (!socket || socket.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
                alert("socket not connected");
            }
            var data = sendMessage.value;
            socket.send(data);
            commsLog.innerHTML += '<tr>' +
                '<td class="commslog-client">Client</td>' +
                '<td class="commslog-server">Server</td>' +
                '<td class="commslog-data">' + htmlEscape(data) + '</td></tr>';
        };

        connectButton.onclick = function() {
            stateLabel.innerHTML = "Connecting";
            socket = new WebSocket(connectionUrl.value);
            socket.onopen = function (event) {
                updateState();
                commsLog.innerHTML += '<tr>' +
                    '<td colspan="3" class="commslog-data">Connection opened</td>' +
                '</tr>';
            };
            socket.onclose = function (event) {
                updateState();
                commsLog.innerHTML += '<tr>' +
                    '<td colspan="3" class="commslog-data">Connection closed. Code: ' + htmlEscape(event.code) + '. Reason: ' + htmlEscape(event.reason) + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
            };
            socket.onerror = updateState;
            socket.onmessage = function (event) {
                commsLog.innerHTML += '<tr>' +
                    '<td class="commslog-server">Server</td>' +
                    '<td class="commslog-client">Client</td>' +
                    '<td class="commslog-data">' + htmlEscape(event.data) + '</td></tr>';
            };
        };
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// <snippet_UseWebSockets>
var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
};

app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
// </snippet_UseWebSockets>

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image]

- Another option is to use `WebSocketSharp`, which has an `OnMessage` feature. [Reference](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)